# date FORMAT AND EXTRACTING DATE VALUES

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tried to convert date formate so, I can extract values for years I want. please help

I have tried this. the date formate was time stamp. code is successful now the date format is dd-mon-rr but, I am not able to use EXTRACT function to get values for years I want.

```
MM.NEEDDATE

TO_CHAR((SELECT MM.NEEDDATE FROM DUAL ), 'DD-MON-RR') AS MATERIALNEEDDATE
```

I tried this to get value for year > 2018

```
(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(MM.NEEDDATE, 'DD-MON-RR'))> 2018)
```

but I am  getting an error like

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
>   01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

successful to convert date formate Actual formate is timestamp

```
TO_CHAR((SELECT MM.NEEDDATE FROM DUAL ), 'DD-MON-RR') AS MATERIALNEEDDATE
```

unsuccessful to extract date for year >2018 
tried -

```
(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(MM.NEEDDATE, 'DD-MON-RR'))> 2018)
```

> ERROR
>   ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
>   01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

The need date column has date values for many years I want the value for year > 2018 only.

Can I do it without formatting date and how ??

Comment: If `needdate` is already a date or timestamp, why are you calling `to_date()` for it? Just extract the year from the raw value... Neither date nor timestamp has any intrinsic format, but you might have meant 'data type' really; even so there is no need to convert/cast.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the `to_date()`, because you are using `TO_CHAR()` on the column (converting from a string to a string is generally not how the function is used).

Have you tried this?

```
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MM.NEEDDATE) > 2018
```

Or more simply:

```
MM.NEEDDATE >= DATE '2019-01-01'
```

Comment: yes I just tried EXTRACT (YEAR FROM MRL.NEEDDATE)>2018) and it is working. thank you

Comment: i used CAST (MRL.NEEDDATE AS DATE) AS NEEDDATE to change date formate

Comment: @WonderWoman: a `DATE` column does not have "a format". Casting a DATE to DATE won't change anything.